# Proving that $f(x)\geq 0$ on $[0,1)$ when $f(x)$ is continuous and when the Darboux/Riemann integral of $f(x)$ is greater than 0.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuous and defined on $[0,1)$. Also, suppose that the Riemann/Darboux integral $\int_a^b f(x)\geq 0$ on $[0,1)$ for any partition . Show that $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in [0,1)$.

I have tried using the Darboux integral definition to solve it. I know that $$L(f,P)\leq L(f)\leq U(f)\leq U(f,P)$$

I tried to solve it by contradiction. Suppose $f(x_0)< 0$ for some $x_0\in [0,1)$, then we can pick a partition such that $$P=\{a=t_0<t_1<...<x_0<...<t_n=b\}$$
where $a=0,b<1$. Then both $L(f,P)$ and $L(f)$ would be less than zero since the both $L(f)$ and $L(f,P)$ depend on the infinum of $f(x)$. I then tried to prove that this showed that the Riemann/Darboux integral could not be greater than zero, but I got stuck.

I tried another method, this time by direct proof. I used the definition of integrable as meaning $$U(f)=L(f)$$ Then, since $\int_a^b f(x)\geq 0$, I took this to mean that $$U(f)\geq 0$$ $$L(f)\geq 0$$
I then tried to show that $U(f)$ and $L(f)$ could not be greater than $0$ if for some $x_0\in[0,1)$, $f(x_0)<0$. However, I failed again. I am not sure what to do at this point. I am pretty sure I have to use the fact that $f(x)$ is continuous, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that for any partition $P$ and sample points $S$,
$RS(f,P,S) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(s_i)\Delta x_i\geq 0$

Since each $f(x) ≥ 0$ and $\Delta x_i > 0$ for each $i$.

Now let $I = \int_{a}^{b}f$, and suppose for contradiction that $I < 0$. Set  $I = \frac{|I|}{2}$. Then since the integral of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is $I$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ so that if $||P|| < \delta$, $|RS(f,P,S) − I| \leq |I|/2$

So if $P$ is any partition with $||P|| < \delta$, then $RS(f,P,S) < I/2 < 0$,
contradicting the calculation in the ﬁrst paragraph.

Therefore $I ≥ 0$, as required.

Here, I've used $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ so you can do it for your $[0,1)$ interval.